# How do I parse jsonb column value from controller to my view blade?

Tags: json, laravel, controller, laravel-blade, jsonb

I am developing a little web application that has a `user_id` column &   `jsonb` column `information` in the database table, which contains user information. I want to show `Auth::user()` information on my blade file.

the column `information` contains may more arrays, here is the `jsonb` column data.

```
{"work": {"info": "work", "company": "Augnitive", "working_to": "2019-01-02", "designation": "Software Engineer", "working_from": "2019-01-01", "responsibilities": "Hello"}, "contact": {"info": "contact", "email": "ki.tushar21@gmail.com", "mobile": "01681654863", "address": "House 156, Sultangonj, Rayer Bazar Dhaka 1209, West Agargaon, West Agargaon", "facebook": "fb.com", "linkedin": "linkedin.com", "citizenship": "Bangladesh"}, "personal": {"bday": "2019-01-01", "info": "personal", "blood": "A(+VE)", "gender": "Male"}, "education": {"info": "education", "edu_type": "SSC", "institute": "PGJHS", "graduation": "2010"}}
```

I have no idea how to display these data in view from controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        $profile = Auth::user()->profile;
//        return $profile;
        return view('home')->with('profile',json_decode($profile,true));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your view file. I hope this is what you are looking for -

```
 @foreach($profile as $key => $val)

    <h3> {{ $key }} </h3>

    @foreach($val as $k => $v)

            <p> {{ $k }} - {{ $v }}  </p>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Already solved this issue,

Controller: //

```
  public function index()
    {
        $profile = Auth::user()->profile->information;
        return view('home')->with(['profile' => $profile]);
    }
```

and in blade view i displayed the data like this

```
{{ $profile['work']['designation'] }}
```